# Customizing an AJAX AutoCompleteExtender with a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, checkbox, autocompleteextender

I wanted to implement a multi-select AutoCompleteExtender that displays a checkbox on each row. I found some examples that implement checkboxes in dropdown lists, but nothing involving the AutoCompleteExtender. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What control would the AutoCompleteExtender extend - a drop down checkbox list?

The [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16488) has an AutoCompleteExtender to extend textboxes, it's worth downloading and looking at the source to get an idea of how to go about it.

There's also a [walkthrough on how to go about developing your own extenders](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/CreatingNewExtender.aspx)